# Passing collection from WCF to Controller action: it sends some navigation objects as "null"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, linq-to-entities

Following is the structure of my tables.

```
Table: Customer
Columns: Id, CityId, Name, IsActive

Table: City
Columns: Id, CityName
```

I have a WCF method that returns a collection of Customers (IList) 
When I test this in WCF client, and also in debug mode, the method returns "City" object in Customer collection, but when the result is passed from WCF service to MVC action it sending some City as null. Its quite strange, because I can see the "City" object just at the return statement in WCF call is executed, but immediately in MVC controller action, the city is not there for some customers in the collection.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Check the properties of City object, if it has datetime or any enum value which is not able to de serialize.

Comment: It has only quite primitive fields, int, and string

Comment: Ok, further to mention, I haven't done anything special for serialization or deserialization. is it required anyway? WCF call is just fetching data from table, and passing it to MVC application.

Comment: Please post some code that exhibits the behavior you're describing.

Comment: ok, adding "serializable" attribute to the type in MVC solved the issue. Thanks Wali for valuable inputs, i got the hint from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the non-primitive properties have to be marked as serializable to make sure the data is received in the UI/Middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

The "Serializable" attribute is required on the type defined as return type.

Comment: yes, the problem is solved, but it wont allow me to accept this as answer till next 2 days.

Comment: Thanks for marking the answer! It shall help others in future!